# Exported Variable Is Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, undefined, module.exports

context:

- object named multiVerse that I need to access in another file that isn't server.js (main file)
- using `module.exports={multiVerse}` in server.js
- requiring the main file using `const {multiVerse} = require('./server.js');`
- when using function to arrange object (made in the same file I require main, calling its class as module on server.js) it tells me multiVerse is undefined
- when requiring the class into server.js to use arrangeBodies() I am doing `const NBody = require('./nbody') const nbody = new NBody();` before the multiVerse object is initialized

questions:

Am I exporting it correctly? Why am I getting undefined?

Comment: To me, this sounds like a [circular dependency issue](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de)

Comment: I'm even exporting a variable that holds a string ```module.exports={test};``` and getting it as ```const{test}=require(./server.js)``` still can't console.log(test) without getting undefined

Comment: Right, it sounds like a circular dependency.  `server.js` imports `nbody.js`, and `nbody.js` imports `server.js`.  That can cause issues.  Without seeing the code it's hard to say for sure, but from the descriptions, I would probably create a `multiverse.js`, which `server` would import.  So server would import multiverse and nbody, nbody would import multiverse, then just make sure multiverse doesn't import server or nbody.  And if it needs to, create *another* file which both multiverse and nbody import from.  You just need to resolve the circular dependency somehow.